# Insert 2 components in nuxt.js page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

i'm new of this framework :(
the problem is here because i've tried to put the component in another page and work it.

It sign error the  component

this is my index.vue page
[image]

Comment: Hi, code screenshot are not allowed here. Please replace it with actual text. Also, what error do you have when you hover your mouse?

Comment: Please share an image as of where is your Slideshow component located in tho.

Comment: don't worry I fixed the problem

Comment: This is not enough here. Please provide more explanation regarding potential future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using nuxt2.0, you should wrap them in a container but this is not needed in nuxt3.0.

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <navbar />
    <slideshow />
  </main>
</template>
```

If this is nuxt2.0, then you should also import the component and register it but you haven't done it here. The path you've given to the component is not correct also.

```html
<script>
import Slideshow from '~/components/slideshow.vue';

export default {
  components: { Slideshow }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The self closing tags may not work on Webpack4, recommending an official opening/closing tag as valid HTML is better as a recommendation. Vite is able to do that itself but still, better recommend the proper way of doing things.

Comment: You're also assuming the path yourself (even if probably right) and suggesting a lowercase casing, while it should be PascalCase.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap the into a div or any other tag (to [not have multiple tags at the root of the `template`](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-multiple-template-root.html)) like that

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <navbar></navbar>
    <slideshow></slideshow>
  </div>
</template>
```

And you can also skip the import part because Nuxt is already doing that for you as explained here: https://nuxtjs.org/tutorials/improve-your-developer-experience-with-nuxt-components/

Comment: This is only one of the possible issues. What about registering the component? What about  Addressing the correct path of the component?

Comment: @Amini I guess you didn't read my answer fully here.